# Excel: How do I calculate net workdays for an array of date ranges?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of date ranges, let's say:

```
        A                   B 
1 April 25, 2013     May 31, 2013
2 September 30, 2013 October 18, 2013
```

I need to calculate a sum of net working days of all ranges into a single cell. I want to avoid intermediate =NETWORKDAYS(). An array formula is a logical choice, but an attempt to apply it, like this `{=SUM(NETWORKDAYS(A1:A2, B1:B2))}` leads to a formula error.

How can it be done?

More broadly, how does Excel apply an array formula? It is not clear to me from basic array formula examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this version

`=SUMPRODUCT(NETWORKDAYS(A1:A2+0, B1:B2+0))`

NETWORKDAYS accepts "arrays" but not ranges (in Excel 2007 or later) so the +0 converts the range to an array

`SUMPRODUCT` instead of `SUM` means you don't need to "array enter" the formula

If you use `SUM` then you "array enter" by doing this:

1) Select cell with formula

2) Press F2 key to select formula

3) Hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> keys and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

if done correctly you get { and } around formula

Comment: I like SUMPRODUCT version.